# Implementing paging for a list

Tags: list, development, csom, paging

I have to implement **paging** for the **list** data and the paging should be as:

> previous  1 2 3  next

And the new page number should be added automatically if any item is added to the list if it exceeds the no of items in the page.

For example:

> records/page = 5 and if in the list the 6th element is added then the page number should be 2 and if I click on any page number it must navigate to the corresponding page with respective records.

I need to implement this in a custom way either by using CSOM or programatically.

Any workaround for this?

Comment: On google you will get so many examples for this.

Comment: but how would you want to implement? In webpart or in list?

You can edit list schema file for adding paging in different list views.